# Проблема с раздачей интернета на компьютер. Your computer appears to be correctly configured but the device or resource is not responding

Tags: windows, сеть

Что бы раздать мобильный интернет на компьютер, мне приходилось менять TTL на 65 в реестре, всё было ок. Но не давно у при раздаче интернета у меня возникла проблема на скриншоте ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше у меня была такая проблема, но я как то её решала и больше меня это не волновало, но сейчас как я не пыталась ничего не работает.

Решение было таким:

1. Нужно было перейти в настройки ipv4 и ipv6 в настройках моей сети и поставить галачку на автоматическое получение ip адресса.
2. После открыть консоль и вести команды ниже:

   `ipconfig /flushdns`

   `ipconfig /registerdns`

   `netsh winsock reset`

   `netsh int ip reset`

   `ipconfig /renew`

После перезапустить компьютер. Козалось бы всё ок, всё работает, но после перезапуска слетает мой TTL в реестре и интернет блочит провайдер. Я подумала ничего страшного и снова изменила TTL на 65, снова перезапускаю и наконец то всё работает, но проблема всё таки осталась, после отключения интернета от раздачи и подключения заново, то появляется снова эта ошибка, и проходится всё снова это проделовать что бы всё заработало.

Так вот я не до конца не могу понять в чем проблема, облазила все форумы, но на них то же самое решение.

Возможно кто то сталкивался с такой проблемой и может мне помочь. Заранее огрномное спасибо =)

Comment: 1) А зачем в конце перезагружать? Вот эта последняя команда заставляет сеть заново переподключиться. Всё должно заработать без перезагрузки. 2) Можно сделать команду изменения TTL в рег-файле. И сделать .cmd файлик, в котором будет сначала запускаться это изменение, а потом все эти команды. И поставить этот файлик в автозагрузку. Может помочь.

Comment: Так, а интернет-то работает при этой ошибке или нет? Я прочитал 2 раза и всё равно не понял.

Comment: Привет @RomanBush, спасибо за совет, сейчас попробую так сделать. Можешь объяснить что делает каждая команда, я конечно могу загуглить, но скорее всего не пойму.

Comment: @donRumata, неа, при этой ошибке интернет не работает.

Comment: Так. Ну а мабила, с которой инет раздаётся - пингуется? А днс гугла? А ya.ru? Я именно про пинги.

Comment: Объяснить могу, но мне точно так же, как и тебе, придётся для этого гуглить. Поэтому моё предложение такое - научись гуглить то, что непонятно. И не используй никогда то, что не понимаешь, как работает. Потому что это очень плохая практика, когда тебе подсовывают какое-то решение, а ты понятия не имеешь, что это и как это работает.